# Navigate from overview to detail page with input

Tags: session, laravel, routes, laravel-5

Little sketch of the situation:
I have an overview page (paginated overview of a Model) with a filtering form. From this overview page you kan navigate to the Model detail page.
On the detail page there is a back link (to go back to the previous page, most of the time this is the overview page, but not necessarily)

What would be the best option to have a user navigate from an overview page to a detail page and back while keeping the input from the overview page (link page number ($_GET param) and the filters input ($_POST parameters)

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Make your back link execute a Javascript history back (So it works like a back button) or use the referrer as the href in your link

Comment: Thats not bad, but imagine this: I select in the overview page a filter and submit the filter form, then I add a second filter option but don't submit the form. I then go to the detail page and back and that second filter option is still checked. Also, I'd prefer not using a link with javascript, but instead do it the Laravel way, flashing the input. Anyhow, this is already a good solution (somehow didn't think about that) but I would like to know if it can be done the laravel way

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's how I did it.

1. Put the filter form values in the session (instead of flashing the input)
2. Form model bind the session values to the form
3. Add a route that removes the session object and redirects to the original route